# Google Calendar API returns 500 error code for every service call

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a Google Calendar integration for a booking application that lets the admins approve/reject bookings. When a booking is approved, it needs to insert an event to a specific Google Calendar that tracks all bookings - for this purpose after reading the docs I decided to use a Service Account and set it up so it has access to modify the calendar and its events.

However, upon submitting any service request I recieve an error with 500 status code and no further explanation on what went wrong during the process.

I have tried to call different methods, e.g. listing events, inserting new ones etc., however all of them fail in the same fashion. I have double checked the JSON file containing the service account credentials, the scopes needed to perform the actions and the service account that I've set up beforehand. Checking the contents of $service after initialized with $client returns information that contains correct data about the specific Google Calendar that the Service Account is allowed to use, which makes me think that the autoloader and the setting of the credentials are correct.

```
session_start();
require_once('./XXX-1234/vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();

$application_creds = './XXX-1234/.json';
$credentials_file = file_exists($application_creds) ? $application_creds : false;
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);
$client->setApplicationName('XXX-1234');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly');

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Test Event',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2019-04-24T00:12:00+02:00',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Budapest',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2019-04-24T00:13:00+02:00',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Budapest',
    ),
));
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

Execution fails on the last line with a 500 error instead of properly inserting the event. The question is, what exactly is the problem here and how could I debug better the cause of this?

Comment: Check your server error logs to see if there's anything there.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try with removing "readonly" scopes. It has already read/write access with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar